# Parallelism with object dependency methods c#

Tags: multithreading, async-await, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Hi i am trying my best to understand that how task run parallel with object dependency methods.
Example: i have list of case data and I want to loop that parallely. Now in the loop i am calling a rest api to get the data by passing Id. And that api data is begin used in some inner methods to perform some curd. So how should I know that paraell.foreach will is calling restapi parallely and the result of api is correctly passed to inner methods to perform curd.?

I have created a object List()
And in foreach loop added the rest api call method to the task list and i have some more method which are async but it used the result of api data. So should I add those methods also in the list?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please share with use the related code fragment?

Comment: The question has no answers because it's unclear. There are no object dependency methods and the typical way of retrieving and saving stuff from APIs is to use a pipeline, not individual objects. `Parallel.ForEach` is only meant for in-memory data parallelism, not executing asynchronous IO operations. Finally, parallelizing database operations typically results in *worse* performance due to blocking